# Index on a list is less than the list size

Tags: c#

I created a methode to Add buttons This is code...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Graphics graphics = this.CreateGraphics();
        SolidBrush brusha = new SolidBrush(Color.Green);
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(50, 10, 200, 200);
        float[] Angels = { 0, 43, 79, 124, 169, 252, 331, 360, 200, 200, 100, 100 };
        Color[] color = {Color.SandyBrown, Color.Cornsilk, Color.Firebrick,Color
                              .OliveDrab, Color.LawnGreen, Color.SandyBrown, Color.Blue};
        grafika.Clear(Color.Ivory);
        int angle;
        for (angle = 1; angle < Angels.Length; angle++)
        {
            brusha.Color = color[angle - 1];
            grafika.FillPie(brusha, rectangle, Angels[angle - 1], Angels[angle] - Angels[anglei - 1]);
        }
        grafika.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, rectangle);
```

When I am running this application I am getting 
"Error Make sure that maximum index on a list is less than the list size" 
Please tell me where I am doing wrong 
Thanks

Comment: The title of the question isn't even remotely connected to the actual question. What?

Comment: `Angels[anglei - 1]` -> what is `anglei`?  Should that be `angle`?

Answer (score 1):

Here :

```
brusha.Color = color[angle - 1];
```

`Angels.length` equals 12, so somewhere along the line, you're doing

```
brusha.Color = color[11];
```

The problem is that the `color` array only has 7 elements, so accessing its 11th element is not possible.